# How to manipulate individual points of instanced curves?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a series of instanced curves. I need to place each end of them in an individual position.
Please help.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean  by "place each end of them in an individual position"? Do you want to scale them so that they touch the second curve, or move the last point on the second curve?

Comment: Place the last point of each curve on the second curve (or anywhere else one by one)

Comment: Ok, I've already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "manipulate individual points of instanced curves" Instances must contain the same data inside each instance. To do that you want you have to convert instances in a bunch of curves. **Realize instances** can do that.

[image]

Now, you can set a position of each point in the curves using **set position** node. (without Realize instances, you set position of instance instead). You can limit the points by using **End point selection**, which can select only the last points in the curves. To get positions I recommend using **Transfer attribute** In index mode, divide index by 2 because there are 2 points in each curve.